# Parse.com & Setup Database / Class

Tags: database, class, parse-platform, model

I'm currently testing Parse and I faced to some issues / challenges.
Assume that I have (its just for an example), on my phone, 3 screens:

- one for the menu
- one for recipes linked to the menu
- one for the ingredients linked to the recipes

I'm wondering how to configure Parse database to have the link between the database/class:
- having one class for all the menu, one class for all the recipes and one class with all the ingredients where there is a link between the menu, the linked recipes to it and the the linked ingredients to the recipes ?

I was thinking to a Pointer but I don't know how to link to specific database to display the right menu with the right recipes with the right ingredients.

Thank you

Regards

Comment: Sounds like a plan (though it's too broad as a question), try it out.

Comment: I take in account your remarks. Edit done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look towards relationships instead of pointers. Pointers are 'to-one' where as relationships are 'to-many' and each of your classes has many associated others. I.e. 1 `Menu` has many `Recipe`s, each `Recipe` has many `Ingredients`.

For your ingredients, consider also that you have an `Ingredient`, but you also have an amount of that ingredient. `Ingredient`s can be reused across recipes (and you may want to do that so you can query all the recipes which include one or more ingredients), but amounts aren't really reusable. So, you may actually want an `IngredientAmount` class so your `Recipe` has a relationship to `IngredientAmount`s and each `IngredientAmount` has a pointer to the associated `Ingredient`.